# Go: Loadbalancing with the default RPC package?

Tags: go, load-balancing, rpc

Is there a way for loadbalancing RPC calls with the default [rpc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) package in go?

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding the tcp traffic works fine. There are even some load balancing tools made with go: https://github.com/darkhelmet/balance